# Too many database connection php

Tags: php, database, pdo

In my `logout.php` endpoint I'm using 3 different classes. Each of this 3 classes have:

```
private $conn;
private $table_name = "users";

// constructor with $db as database connection
public function __construct($db)
{
    $this->conn = $db;
}
```

this code in order to connect to database from endpoint while initializing class like so:

```
// include needed files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../classes/user.php';
include_once '../classes/token.php';

// instantiate database and product object
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// initialize object
$user = new user($db);
$token = new token($db);
```

In this 3 classes in some functions I sometimes need to use other class so I additionally include [database class](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4031bbc7ce368d02df999a4faca4a293) once again like in this logout function within *user* class:

```
public function logout($receivedToken)
{
    include_once '../config/database.php';
    include_once '../classes/token.php';

    // instantiate database
    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $token = new token($db);
    if($token->checkToken($receivedToken))
```

And I'm not sure if it is correct approach I'm debugging my code and trying to refactor it to make more sense. Do I need to include this db once again there in logout function within user class in order to use token class? Or maybe I can somehow use this connection which I did initialize in endpoint via `__construct` and not `include` database over and over again?

Comment: You could use a DI framework and a class autoloader

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bad approach, first of all, you should only `include` once at the top of your file.

There is no need to include it again in the logout method and generally `includes` inside of method bodies are usually a code smell in my opinion, except in some specific cases.

Secondly you are making two many connections to your database, every time you instantiate the Database class `$database = new Database()` and call `$database->getConnection()` you are making a new connection to the database. You should only instantiate Database once, and then inject it  into classes that need DB connection (pass it through constructor or as a method param).

Last but not the least, you should ensure that your `$database->getConnection()` returns a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

You can do that like this

```
<?php
    class Database
    {
        // specify your own database credentials
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $db_name = "obiezaca_db";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";
        private $conn;
        // get the database connection

        public function getConnection()
        {
            if (!$this->conn) {
                try {
                    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
                    $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
                } catch(PDOException $exception) {
                    // you shouldn't output exception error message in production
                    // because it can leak sensitive data such as DB username and password
                    echo "Database error";
                }
            }  
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }
?>
```

Or you could make a Singletton factory like this

```
<?php
    class Database 
    {
        // specify your own database credentials
        private $host = "localhost";
        private $db_name = "obiezaca_db";
        private $username = "root";
        private $password = "";

        private $conn;

        private static $instance;

        private function __construct() {};

        private function __clone() {};

        public static getInstance() 
        {
            if (!static::$instance) {
                static::$instance = new Database(); 
            } 
            return static::$instance;
        }

        // get the database connection
        public function getConnection()
        {
            if (!$this->conn) {
                try {
                    $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
                    $this->conn->exec("set names utf8");
                } catch(PDOException $exception) {
                    // you shouldn't output exception error message in production
                    // because it can leak sensitive data such as DB username and password
                    echo "Database error";
                }
            }  
            return $this->conn;
        }
    }

 $database = Database::getInstance();
 $connection = $database->getConnection();
```

In this approach no matter how many times in your code you call these methods you will always get the same `Database` and `PDO` object instances.

This way you will ensure that you always have one connection to your database, and additionally your database will be globally accessible since it is accessed statically.

Comment: Thanks for respond it was very helpful for me. With this constructor I now initialize my classes like so: `$token = new token($this->conn)` and now I could delete `include database` because I'm actually using contructor. And I moved `include token` to the top of file before class declaration. Is it better now?

Comment: @BT101 you need to pass them like this `$token = new token($db->getConnection());`, because `$conn` is a private property to make sure that it cannot be altered from outside the class.

Comment: It's working just fine with `$token = new token($this->conn)` when private conn is set like so: `public function __construct($db) { $this->conn = $db; }` where parameter `$db` is `$db->getConnection()` indeed `$db = $database->getConnection(); $user= new user($db);`