# PHP - PDO OOP MySQL database connection is being repeated, is that a normal behavior?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, pdo

I am using a class for db connection like this...

```
class Dbh
{
    private $host;
    private $dbName;
    private $password;
    private $dbUser;
    private $charset;

    protected function connect ()
    {
        $this->host = 'localhost';
        $this->dbName = 'test';
        $this->password = '';
        $this->dbUser = 'root';
        $this->charset = 'utf8mb4';
        try
        {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbName . ';charset=' . $this->charset;
            $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbUser, $this->password);
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $pdo;
        }
        catch (PDOException $exception)
        {
            $message = 'Connection failed:' . $exception->getMessage();
            return $message;
        }
    }

}
```

... Now what worries me if I echo in `try` for example `echo 'Connected';` and call for example...

```
$user = new User();
$users = $user->getAllUsers();
$update = $user->updateUser();
$insert = $user->insertUsers();
```

It will output 3 times 'Connected' on a page, where it should do probably only once as 1 connection is enough.

How to fix this?

Comment: `User` < where's that class and where are you echoing?

Comment: The user class is just a simple `$stmt = $this->connect()->query('SELECT * FROM users');` and such queries which i output on my index page for testing purpose

Comment: So you are calling `->connect()` on each query. Logically, you are connecting again on each query. I'm confused about the confusion here.

Comment: This may be a good use-case for the _singleton_ design pattern - https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php

Comment: Well, the thing is, is that a normal behavior? Because on youtube I found a video where a guy is explaining that it shouldn't behave this way. The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3_alwb6Twiw&list=PLfdtiltiRHWF5Rhuk7k4UAU1_yLAZzhWc&index=7

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48013188/too-many-database-connection-php

Comment: Of course not, it is not normal. Are you buying a new car every time you need a ride? Probably not. Why do you have an idea to connect to a database every time you want to run a query? 

The accepted answer just sweeps the problem under the rug. It is not only keeps a User a descendant of a Database (quite a weird ancestry) but also keeps that habit of connecting every time you need to run a query. Given you are just learning and there is no legacy code to keep, the accepted answer is a deliberate disservice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A simple fix would be to set the connection as a class variable and check for it.  So `connect()` may still be called multiple times from `User` but there will be only one actual connection. Simplified:

```
class Dbh
{
    private $pdo = null;

    protected function connect ()
    {
        if($this->pdo === null) {
            $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $this->dbUser, $this->password);
        }
        return $this->pdo;
    }
}
```

This would only connect once for an instance of `$user = new User();` however it would connect again for `$cart = new Cart()` etc. if that extends the `Dbh` class.

If starting from scratch there are better ways, maybe [Singleton Pattern](https://phpenthusiast.com/blog/the-singleton-design-pattern-in-php), but this way you only need to modify `Dbh` and not refactor all of the other classes.

Comment: See edit, singleton would be better.

Comment: Yeah i'm starting from scratch and trying to get a proper db connection for pdo oop